# Dockerized flask app builds and runs locally but wont work when deployed on Azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, flask, dockerfile

I'm attempting to deploy a flask web app using a docker container. I'm dockerizing the app because I have a package (RDKit) which cannot be pip installed and must be done using conda.

When using 
`docker run my_image`

I get an import error for flask - the first library that my python script imports. However, I'm able to deploy the app locally when I specify the port using the command: `docker run -p 80:80 my_image`. I have a feeling that my Dockerfile might be the problem:

```
FROM cameroncruz/flask-nginx-uwsgi-miniconda:python3.6

# Create conda env (base image is built on python 3.6 and will have to migrate to 3.7 later)
RUN conda create --name myenv python=3.6

# Install the required dependencies
RUN /bin/bash -c ". activate myenv && \
    conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    conda install -y \
        scikit-learn \
        numpy \
        scipy \
    rdkit \
    wtforms \
    ipython \
        flask \
        uwsgi"

# Copy custom supervisor config
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Copy application files

# The application to be served
COPY server/main.py /app/main.py

# Folder containing the styling
COPY server/static/ /app/static

# Folder containing the html
COPY server/templates/ /app/templates

# The trained machine learning model
copy server/model.pkl /app/model.pkl

# EXPOSE PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

The beginning of my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, json
```

The end of my python code:

```
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Here is the supervisord.conf file:

```
nodaemon=true

[program:uwsgi]
environment=PATH='/opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin'
command=/opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term --need-app

stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
# Graceful stop, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
stopsignal=QUIT
```

I have deployed apps on Azure before but this is my first time with a container. I'm also using Ubuntu 18.04, if that matters. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What does Docker logs say?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne - Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
     from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, json
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: Looks like the vertualenv isn't active. You can use the solution from the link above to activate it. Or write a `entrypoint` script that activates the using the `. activate myenv` everytime the container spin up.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Hey Praveen, thanks for your time and help! I removed the venv entirely since the image itself is an environment and it worked. However, the Azure deployment is still a problem.